# How to run Applescript from java package

Tags: java, swing, shell, applescript

I'm trying to run my applescript in my system like this.

```
String cmd = "osascript " + cmdpath + "ReadNeofile.scpt";
UnixComm(cmd);
```

I used Java Swing to developed the system and its a standalone system.
The code working fine where I able to run the applescript and get the input. My biggest drawback is, to do this I need to save the apple script in client pc. Is there any ways where I can call the applescript from java packages since saving scripts in client pc wont be safe. I scared if my client accidentally delete the script, my entire system will be corrupted. Please advice.

Comment: Did you try [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=java+run+applescript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can throw the code into a variable, (in this example, it's called codeVar) and escape all the newlines and quotes, then change the code to:

```
String cmd = "osascript " + cmdpath + "<( echo '" + codeVar + "')";
UnixComm(cmd);
```

---

Another solution would be to have the code put the applescript in a file in `/tmp`, and run the code in /tmp, where the client hopefully won't delete it. (and the code is deleted by the computer after you're done using it)
The example for that is:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/tmp/myapplescript.scpt");
out.print(codeVar);
String cmd = "osascript " + cmdpath + "/tmp/myapplescript.scpt";
UnixComm(cmd);
```

Both solutions require that you have the applescript, with the return characters escaped (replace them with `\n`), and probably also, the double quotes, if any (replace them with `\"`)